# jQuery and Validation plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a drop down called `answerYesNo_1`. If user picks "yes" option, I want to force the user to enter a valid monetary value to `answerYesNoText_1` field. How do I chain these two rules? I am having a little bit of a trouble here. The code below validates when the option yes is selected. However, I can enter values like "asdad" and it will pass. It is as if I want to say, yes it is required, and yes go do the test.

```
rules: {
            answerYesNoText_1: { required : { depends:function(){ if ($('#answerYesNo_1').val() == 'yes') {  
                if ( /^\$?[0-9][0-9\,]*(\.\d{1,2})?$|^\$?[\.]([\d][\d]?)$/.test($('#answerYesNoText_1').val()) != true ) {          
                    return true;}  }  } 
                                            }
                                }
    },
```

and here is my fields:

```
 <select name="answerYesNo_1" id="answerYesNo_1" style="width:60px; font-size:11px;">
     <option value=""></option>
     <option value="yes">Yes</option>
     <option value="no">No</option>
 </select>
 <input type="text" name="answerYesNoText_1" id="answerYesNoText_1" class="answers" value="" maxlength="60" />
```

Answer (score 1):

One way out is to use mask to force the user enter a valid monetary number. I've been using maskmoney for it and works really well.

https://github.com/plentz/jquery-maskmoney

```
if($('#answerYesNo_1 option:selected').val() == 'yes'){
   $("#answerYesNoText_1").maskMoney();
}
```

Comment: I have a change event attached to answerYesNoText_1. When I use your maskMoney(), the change event is no longer triggered.

Comment: @FALCONSEYE could you try the last version?

Answer (score 0):

Try this to check if the input is a number instead of that mind-bogglingly overcomplicated Regex you had going there:

```
if (!isNaN(parseFloat($('#answerYesNoText_1').val()))) {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I want to let them enter values like $23,000.32.

Comment: @FALCONSEYE: Ah, in that case, see my updated answer. I used `parseFloat` instead of creating a new `Number`, as that handles decimal points nicely.

Comment: The thing is I want to make it required and also a valid money value. When I use these, it becomes not a money value, then it is not required. When it a money value, then it is required.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to separate the `required` and the valid monetary rule, something like:

```
rules: {
    answerYesNoText_1: {
        required: function(){
            if ($('#answerYesNo_1').val() == 'yes'){
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

and add a validation rule for the monetary value check using `$.validator.addMethod` given your regular expression is correct.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is add an onchange event handler to the select element which would add a validation class to the text input field when "yes" is selected, and to remove that class when it's not. You may have to re-initialize the form validation object every time, but at least the validation would appear to "chain" this way.